# convert an matrix like object to a matrix

Tags: r

I am using the very useful package `Markovchain`. Here is my code:

```
df<-c(10,12,14,1,5,6,7,8,9,2,3,4,5)
c<-markovchainFit(df,method = "mle")
c$estimate
```

The result is in the class of markovchain. How can I convert this object to a matrix?

Comment: From looking at `str(c$estimate)` maybe this, `c$estimate@transitionMatrix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work -

```
c$estimate[]
```